# custom formula conditional formating - Only weekedays and 3 days in future

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Can anyone shed light on the following dilemma, please?
I have the need for a custom formula that allows conditional formatting for any rows who's date in columnB is 3 weekdays AHEAD of today's current date.
For example, if today was Wednesday 12/3  then I need to format any rows who's colB date is 3 working days in the future Thus  (Monday 12/8)  would be formatted....skipping any weekend days. No other days before or after (Monday 12/8) would be formatted.
To explain the premise, Sales staff can view this page and know that all jobs due to be installed 3 days from today (highlighted, say in yellow) must be turned in for processing today. Thus the need to exclude all weekend days.
This forum has helped me so very much to accomplish my Production Schedule using Sheets, as I have zero experience. You guys have been the best and I am in hopes this too can be resolved.

For reference you can view the test data sheet  named  "DUE_AMBER" at the below link where all rows having date of "Mon, Dec 8" would be only rows impacted
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1goG0TS1_2jwlGRetREYNRVk-Q6TEy3iWG_5VXFoZlus/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks.

Comment: I found it     =(if(networkdays(TODAY(),(INDIRECT("B"&ROW())))=4,1,0))=1

Answer (score 0):

Seems OP is happy enough with this answer of his own:

```
=(if(networkdays(TODAY(),(INDIRECT("B"&ROW())))=4,1,0))=1
```